# Какой справочник использовать при реализации программы спряжения глаголов?

Tags: русификация

Я пишу open-source библиотеку, которая предназначена для анализа и синтеза словоформ русского языка. Т.е. по заданному слову/словосочетанию/предложению с ее помощью можно будет сказать, какие грамматические формы у каждой лексемы, входящей в заданный текст (анализ), и наоборот - для заданного слова/словосочетания преобразовать их в указанную грамматическую форму (синтез).

Для имен (т.е. существительных, прилагательных, числительных, причастий и др - все, кроме глаголов) существует прекрасная работа [А. А. Зализняка "Русское именное словоизменение"](http://www.inslav.ru/resursy/elektronnaya-biblioteka/1116-zaliznyak-a-a-qrusskoe-imennoe-slovoizmenenieq-s-prilozheniem-izbrannyx-rabot-po-sovremennomu-russkomu-yazyku-i-obshhemu-yazykoznaniyu-m-2002), в которой досконально разобраны все случаи и дан конкретный полный алгоритм анализа и синтеза словоформ. При этом алгоритме Зализняка учитываются все тонкие моменты (например, большинство библиотек не может адекватно разобрать оба выражения "тормоза автомобиля" и "тормозы экономического развития" и многие другие).

Существует ли аналогичная работа по спряжению глаголов?

Comment: Библиотека [pymorphy2](https://github.com/kmike/pymorphy2) использует данные проекта [opencorpora](http://opencorpora.org/), возможно и вы найдете там то что вам нужно.